# Cannot find module 'stream-browserify'

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am using ionic4, i have installed all dependencies. But when i am doing npm install then it is showing all up to date. But when i am running application by ionic serve, It is giving error of 'Cannot find module 'stream-browserify'. I have agin installed specific dependency of 'stream-browserify'. Still getting same error. Please help me to out of this.

Comment: can you put the error up along with your question?

Comment: What peer dependency warnings do you get when you run `npm install`?

Comment: @nash11, Below is the error,   
ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
[ng] Cannot find module 'stream-browserify'
[ng] Error: Cannot find module 'stream-browserify'
[ng]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
[ng]     at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
[ng]     at Object.<anonymous> (F:\git\crane_system_ionic4\node_modules\node-libs-browser\index.js:24:31)
[ng]     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
[ng]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)

Answer (score 2):

Try with these

```
npm install -g ionic@latest
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
```